# Unable to kick out some unwanted values from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a script in vba to clear any cell containing ***#NAME?***. However, every time I run my following macro I get this `cel.value=Error 2029`.

I've tried with:

```
Sub ClearUnwantedRange()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.CurrentRegion
        If InStr(cel, "#")  > 0 Then
            Debug.Print cel.Address
            cel.ClearContents
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

I even tried with `If InStr(cel, "#NAME?") > 0 Then` but no luck.

> ***How can I kick those unwanted values out?***

Comment: I tried with `cel`, `cel.Value` and `cel.Text` but the error is still there @Vasily Ivoyzha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
If IsError(cel) Then
```

... instead of ...

```
If InStr(cel, "#")  > 0 Then
```

Comment: That did it @Skin. Thanks a lot.